# "Men of the night" or "the men of the night"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

What's the most grammatical/idiomatic option?

Example sentence:

> It seemed to Mary that (the) men of the night were better at mating
>   than match-making.

(Here Mary is referring to men who frequent bars and clubs.)

Comment: Too small a sample of text to tell, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, and would sound fine in speaking or informal writing.